# Python 3.7.2. curve_fit Построение аппроксимации синусоидальной функцией

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

У меня есть наборы данных time и strain, где strain - зависимая от time переменная, причем зависит по гармоническому закону. Мне нужно построить аппроксимацию этих данных с целью выяснить, во-первых, насколько это выполняется, и, во-вторых, для некоторого дальнейшего использования. Ниже представлен код, как я это делаю:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import cycle_cycle as cyc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def test_sin(x, y0, A, xc, w):
    return y0 + A*np.sin(np.pi*(x-xc)/w)

data = cyc.read_file_exp(file_name_ex)
time = data[250:1000, 0:1]  #Беру срез столбца, для наглядности
strain = data[250:1000, 2:3]

params, cov = curve_fit(test_sin, time.flatten(), strain.flatten())
print(params)

t_strain = test_sin(time, params[0], params[1], params[2], params[3])


plt.plot(time, t_strain, linewidth = 1, marker='.', label= 'Аппроксимация')
plt.plot(time, strain, linewidth = 1, marker='.', label= 'Эксперимент')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
plt.clf()
```

Собственно, результат неудовлетворительный. 
curve_fit выдает параметры 
[-33.324, -32.761, -2.038, -4.561], 
в то время как OriginLab 8.1. выдает подобное [-0.604, 2.539, 0.061, 0.028]. Что неидельно, но гораздо ближе к правде.
Ниже примеры графиков, построенных с аппроксимацией curve_fit'ом и Ориджином.
[image: Что дает аппроксимация в ориджине][image: Что дает curve_fit]

Собственно, мой вопрос в том, правильно ли я вообще использую curve_fit? или есть какие-то ошибки и/или тонкости в работе с ним? Или он вообще для подобной задачи не помощник и нужно пользоваться чем-то другим?

Comment: можете выложить ваши данные в CSV или в Excel формате на какой-нибудь файлообменник?

Comment: Ссылка на файл с данными на google drive. В нем 4 стобца, интересны 1 - time, и 3 - strain. https://drive.google.com/file/d/14ZfOAnAjFYnRBMbRC6Cfq2xrSeTMNmfJ/view?usp=sharing